# Detect key binding collisions in sublime text

Tags: sublime-text-2

In sublime text is there any way in to detect when a particular key binding is already assigned to some command and is then overwritten?

I just want to be able to detect such scenarios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a matter of fact, there's a plugin for that! skuroda's [`FindKeyConflicts`](https://github.com/skuroda/FindKeyConflicts) is just what you're looking for, and is also available through [Package Control](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control). It's incredibly helpful if you're a package developer, or just have a ton of plugins.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article on official forum](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/how-to-show-command-name-binded-to-a-certain-key/4322), you can enable logging of command execution:

```
sublime.log_commands(True)
```